ckfinder 3 config file and CakePHP 5
How to insert CakePHP5 session into ckfinder config file? Are there any restrictions? The problem is that within the ckfinder config file I cannot retrieve the global session variable.
I tried the following code but it doesn't work:
if (!empty($_SESSION['Auth']['AdminUser'])) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}


"it doesn't work" - what does that mean? And how is this problem related to CakePHP?

I expect this would very much depend on the order in which files are loaded.
